# saving ms word docx file using edraw in php

Tags: php, file, ms-word, save, docx

I have used the following code for saving open docx file.

javascript:

```
function SavetoServer(){
    OA1.Save();
    OA1.CloseDoc();
    OA1.HttpInit();
    OA1.HttpAddPostFile("C:\wamp\www\rte\sample2.docx");
    document.OA1.HttpPost("http://localhost/rte/actor2.php");

}
```

php code "actor2.php"

```
<?php
    header("http/1.1 200 OK");
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['trackdata']['name'],"w+");
    if($handle == FALSE)
    {
      exit("Create file error!");
    }
    $handle2 = fopen($_FILES['trackdata']['tmp_name'],"r");
    $data = fread($handle2,$_FILES['trackdata']['size']);
    fwrite($handle,$data);
    fclose($handle2);
    fclose($handle);
    exit(0);
  ?>
```

The file is not saving when we changed in browser. Can anyone see a problem with this?

Comment: Finally i have fixed the javascript code lines.
    user these below three lines in javascript function.

    OA1.HttpAddPostFile("C:\wamp\www\rte\sample2.docx");
    OA1.HttpAddPostOpenedFile("sample2.docx");
    OA1.HttpPost("http://localhost/rte/actor2.php");

Comment: strange because with JS you cannot access to the computer folders! Security restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

The HttpAddPostFile can add only the file from the remote website. It does work for the local disk file.

```js
function SavetoServer()
{
 if(document.OA1.IsOpened)
 {
  document.OA1.SetAppFocus();
  document.OA1.HttpInit(); 
  var sFileName = document.OA1.GetDocumentName();

  document.OA1.HttpAddPostOpenedFile (sFileName); //save as the same file format with the sFileName then upload
  //document.OA1.HttpAddPostOpenedFile (sFileName, 16); //save as docx file then upload
  //document.OA1.HttpAddPostOpenedFile (sFileName, 0); //save as doc file then upload
  //document.OA1.HttpAddPostOpenedFile (sFileName, -4143); //save as xls file then upload
  //document.OA1.HttpAddPostOpenedFile (sFileName, 51); //save as xlxs file then upload
  
  document.OA1.HttpPost("upload_weboffice.php");
  if(document.OA1.GetErrorCode() == 0 || document.OA1.GetErrorCode() == 200)
  {  
   var sPath = "Save successfully! You can download it at http://www.ocxt.com/demo/" + sFileName;
   window.alert(sPath);
  }
  else
  {
   window.alert("you need enable the IIS Windows Anonymous Authentication if you have not set the username and password in the HttpPost method. you need set the timeout and largefile size in the web.config file.");
  }
 }
 else{
  window.alert("Please open a document firstly!");
 }
}


upload_weboffice.php

<?php

$sql = sprintf("username=%s  passwd=%s  param=%s", $_POST['user'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['param']);
echo $sql;

$filecount = count($_FILES["trackdata"]["name"]);
echo "\r\n";
echo "file account:";
echo $filecount;
echo "\r\n";

$sql = sprintf("file=%s  size=%s error=%s tmp=%s", $_FILES['trackdata']['name'],$_FILES['trackdata']['size'],$_FILES['trackdata']['error'],$_FILES['trackdata']['tmp_name']);
echo $sql;
echo "\r\n";

$filen = $_FILES['trackdata']['name'];
//$filen = iconv("UTF-8", "GBK", $filen);
$handle = fopen($filen,"w+");
if($handle == FALSE)
{
 exit("Create file error!");
}

$handle2 = fopen($_FILES['trackdata']['tmp_name'],"r");
$data = fread($handle2,$_FILES['trackdata']['size']);
echo $data;

//file_put_contents($handle, "\xEF\xBB\xBF".  $data);
//fwrite($handle,pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf));
fwrite($handle,$data);

fclose($handle2);
fclose($handle);


exit(0);
?>
```

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality up